# Nested LiNQ to XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I am looking for a nice way to save / load the following.
I want to save as XML and ideally looking to use LiNQ (namely to help me learn LINQ)

I don't know how to do nested linq writes though.  Can anyone help?

```
    /// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
public class ErrorType
{
    List<ErrorType> _childErrors;

    public String Name { get; set; }
    public bool Ignore { get; set; }

    public List<ErrorType> ChildErrors { get; protected set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
public class ErrorList
{
    public List<ErrorType> ChildErrors { get; protected set; }

    public void Save()
    {
    }

    public void Load()
    {
    }
}
```

Essentially the ErrorList contains a top level list of Errors, each error can have children.
The XML output should look something like:

```
<ErrorList>
<ErrorName1 Ignore="false">
<ChildErrorName1 Ignore="true">
<ChildErrorName2 Ignore="false" />
</ChildErrorName1>
</ErrorName1>
<ErrorList>
```

If anyone could help that would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I see what you're after now. Try this:

```
// Need to declare in advance to call within the lambda.
Func<ErrorType, XElement> recursiveGenerator = null;
recursiveGenerator = error => new XElement
    (error.Name,
     new XAttribute("Ignore", error.Ignore),
     error.ChildErrors.Select(recursiveGenerator));

var errorList = new XElement
    ("ErrorList", errors.ChildErrors.Select(recursiveGenerator));
```

Here's a complete example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class ErrorType
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public bool Ignore { get; set; }

    public List<ErrorType> ChildErrors { get; protected set; }
    public ErrorType()
    {
        ChildErrors = new List<ErrorType>();
    }
}

public class ErrorList
{
    public List<ErrorType> ChildErrors { get; protected set; }
    public ErrorList()
    {
        ChildErrors = new List<ErrorType>();
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var childError2 = new ErrorType { 
            Name = "ChildErrorName2", Ignore=false };
        var childError1 = new ErrorType {
            Name = "ChildErrorName1", Ignore=true,
            ChildErrors = { childError2 }
        };
        var mainError = new ErrorType {
            Name = "ErrorName1", Ignore=true,
            ChildErrors = { childError1 }
        };
        var errorList = new ErrorList { ChildErrors = { mainError } };

        // Need to declare in advance to call within the lambda.
        Func<ErrorType, XElement> recursiveGenerator = null;
        recursiveGenerator = error => new XElement
            (error.Name,
             new XAttribute("Ignore", error.Ignore),
             error.ChildErrors.Select(recursiveGenerator));

        var element = new XElement
             ("ErrorList", 
              errorList.ChildErrors.Select(recursiveGenerator);

        Console.WriteLine(element);
    }        
}
```

Comment: Cheers Jon that looks about right.
I tested it though and it has a compiler error on the line:  errorList.ChildErrors.Select(recursiveGenerator(x));

I replaced X with errorList.ChildErrors[0] to match the correct type but no joy. My lambda skills are weak so couldn't figure out what was going wrong.

Comment: Whoops, fixed that - it should be errorList.ChildErrors.Select(recursiveGenerator);

Comment: (I used to have errorList.ChildErrors.Select(x => recursiveGenerator(x)) which is a bit redundant.)

Comment: Thanks that looks good, how would I reverse this to actually load data from an XElement?

Comment: So far I have this...
     private ErrorList FromXmlToErrorList(XElement xd)
        {
            List<ErrorType> typeList = (from error in xd.Descendants()
                            select new ErrorType
                            {
                                Name = error.Value,
                                Ignore = bool.Parse(error.Attribute("Ignore").Value)
                                ChildErrors= /*Lambda ?*/
                            }).ToList<ErrorType>();

            ErrorList el = new ErrorList();
            el.ChildErrors = typeList;
            return el;
        }

Comment: Um, I suggest you ask in a separate question - it'll be slightly messy to mix up that with the answer here (which is already quite long). I'll happily answer though :)

Comment: Cheers dude I'll get on it :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456231/xmlserialization-of-mutiple-object-types-in-the-one-list). It should be what you are looking for. No LINQ thought but rather nice and easy way of outputting XML.

The bottom line though is to use [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx).